# Change divider color of DrawerHeader

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to remove or change color to transparent of divider of DrawerHeader (grey line on the screen), but solutions from another questions doesn't work for me.

Here is my code:

```
drawer: const Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.0))),
              child: Center(child: Text('Hello World')),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

If I increase the thickness of the border, the new colorful line will appear above the gray line, which also does not suit me.

Comment: A simple way of solving it will be just using a container/ SizedBox  with Align widget.You can checkout the [default size for DrawerHeader](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2216a78095fcd6f9914dcbf895b6ca891cbb83a4/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/drawer_header.dart#L11)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Drawer` widget in `Theme` and set the divider color and theme according to your design like this:

```
Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
          dividerTheme: DividerThemeData(
            color: Colors.transparent,
          ),
        ),
        child: Drawer(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              DrawerHeader(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border(
                        bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.0))),
                child: Center(child: Text('Hello World')),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

You can also set your theme in the Material widget for the whole app.

Answer (score 0):

In your theme declaration file, add a dividerTheme like so,

```
dividerTheme: const DividerThemeData(
  color: Colors.red
),
```

This should set the divider colour to red.